# IntelliJ - Scala: String class is broken

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have been trying to use and setup IntelliJ for a Scala-Project. However, I get the following error message (see below) Can anyone help me to figure out a solution? Thank you very much! (Some information: I have the Scala plugin and sbt installed (latest version); the sbt file specifies scala 2.13.0 and I have a JDK of version 13).

-server -Xmx1536M -Dsbt.supershell=false -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar C:\Users\pajor.IdeaIC2019.3\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar early(addPluginSbtFile=\"\"\"C:\Users\pajor\AppData\Local\Temp\idea2.sbt\"\"\") "; set ideaPort in Global := 56260 ; idea-shell"
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)

Comment: What if you use JDK 8? https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2.13.0 is incompatible with JDK 13. Either upgrade your project to Scala 2.13.1, or use JDK 8 | 11.

Comment: Thank you both - this fixed my problem! Everything is fine with JDK11